# what is purpose of the throttler class,when i can simply use time.sleep()

Tags: python, class, time, delay

```
class Throttle:
    #add delay between download for eacch delay
    def __init__(self,delay):
        #amount of delay between downloads
        self.delay=delay
        #timestamp of when a domain was last accessed
        self.domains={}

    def wait(self,url):
        domain=urlparse.urlparse(url).netloc
        last_accessed=self.domains.get(domain)
        if self.delay > 0 and last_accessed is not None:
            sleeps_secs=self.delay-(datetime.datetime.now()-last_accessed).seconds
            if sleeps_secs > 0:
                #domain has been recently accessed
                #so we need to sleep
                time.sleep(sleeps_secs)
        #update last accessed time
        self.domains[domain]=datetime.datetime.now()
```

can someone explain to me how this works and why this is useful? .. i got it from a book ,
Also why not just use `time.sleep(2)` instead of this

Comment: This class doesn't simply sleep, it accesses an url and computes delays. Of course there are infinite ways you can implement the same. You may use only functions and no classes, for example. But this is another point. `Throttle` has different functionalities than `time.sleep()` they don't do the same thing.

Comment: The comments explain it, it is a conditional sleep.